Datatable multiple class options: nowrap text and no row shading
I am trying to pass different class options to datatable in my Shiny app (https://datatables.net/manual/styling/classes).
In particular, I want no wrapping of cell content, and avoid alternate row shading.
I can accomplish this separately:
datatable(mydata, class = "display nowrap")

or
datatable(mydata, class = list(stripe = FALSE))

but I cannot make them work together. I tried all the following options, with no success (no error, just one of the two things won't work):
datatable(mydata, class = list("display nowrap", stripe = FALSE))
datatable(mydata, class = list("display nowrap", list(stripe = FALSE)))
datatable(mydata, class = list(nowrap = TRUE, stripe = FALSE))
datatable(mydata, class = "display nowrap", class = list(stripe = FALSE))

Is there a way to pass multiple class options?

You are adding the stripe style implicitly via display. Set the class to nowrap and it will be disabled. Also, then you can implement additional adjustments for the further things which display sets (e.g. row highlighting on hover).

Thanks for the comment. What would be the final code line then? Thanks again!

The doc you linked says that display is the combination of "Short-hand for the stripe, hover, row-border and order-column classes." So you have to include the classes you want separately.

Attempts like datatable(mydata, class = list("display nowrap", stripe = FALSE)) can't work because with display you implicitly also set stripe. From the docs:

display:   Short-hand for the stripe, hover, row-border and
order-column classes.

So if you wan't to have nowrap, no stripe and everything else which comes from display, you could set the class like this:
datatable(mydata, class = "hover row-border order-column nowrap")

